# REGEXMATCH on double quote character?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to do a conditional formatting that matches on the double quote character followed by a zero. i.e.

"0 / 10" : this should match as true

"10 / 10": this should match as false

This regex is incorrect, as it matches on both:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B;"0 /")
```

I expect to be able to use the formula standard of escaping the " with an extra quote. It accepts this formula syntactically, but does not match:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B;"""0 /")
```

I tried matching with punctuation characters, no match:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B;"[[:punct:]]0 /")
```

I can use [digit[ to match the 10/10 case, but ~digit doesn't match the zero with a quote in front of it:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B;"[^[:digit:]]0 /")
```

I even tried concatenating the specific character, no match:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B:B;CONCATENATE(CHAR(34), "0 /"))
```

I'm very confused at this point. If I insert any other special character before the zero, I have no trouble matching it. But it seems like double-quote just isn't treated like a regular character somehow. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Regarding the `=REGEXMATCH(B:B;"""0 /")` option, which should have worked, are you certain that the actual value has a literal double quote in front of it?

Comment: Oh this is a good hint, I thought so but maybe not. Does it matter if what is inside the cell is a formula? It seems to. I just checked and I can match if it's plain text. But what is actually in the cell I'm trying to match is a =hyperlink formula, e.g.:

=HYPERLINK("https://some_URL", "0 / 10")

On this, it cannot match?

Comment: Ah thanks Tim you pointed me in the direction to find a solution. I need to extract the formula text. This works:

=REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT($B1);"""0 /")

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2;char(34)&"0 /")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1863229) for giving me a hint that lead to a solution. My problem was that the text in a cell was part of a formula. So I needed to extract the formula as text (`FORMULATEXT`) and then it works:

```
=REGEXMATCH(FORMULATEXT($B1);"""0 /")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in row 1 of a different column:

```
=arrayformula(if(B:B<>"",iferror(regexmatch(B:B,"""0"),),))
```

`if(B:B<>""` will only process the formula provided Col B has values.

`iferror(` will ignore numbers in Col B that produce `#VALUE!`.

`"""0"` is the regex. The double quote to the left of `0` is doubled up (or `char(34)&"0"` as per @Mike Steelson).